# Can SonarQube sent notification after scan to group with only email? (without password authentication)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I’m using SonarQube Community Edition Version 9.9.3 (build 79811) on windows, and did the following steps using Sonar admin user:

1. I created group of users not thought SonarQube but other internal system, and gave this group an email address.
2. I tested it thought sonar admin screen (email test) and it worked (all users in this group got the mail).
3. I created sonar user, and gave him this group email address (since for some strange reason, you can’t assign email to sonar group).
4. I gave this user all the permissions to some empty project I created, and turn on all the project notification (reminder, I’m connected with sonar admin user)
5. I ran scan thought sonar scanner version 5.0.1, but only the admin got the email, and none of the users and group did.
6. I tried the same with other user instead the group, and got the same behavior
7. The only way it worked, is when I logged in with the user from item 6, and set this user to get notification from this project.

This is not good for me as I don’t want to manage the users and group thought Sonar, and also I don’t want to have dependency in user and password authentication for each user in order to get notification.
Does my assumption is correct? any ideas how can I get the expected result per the scenario I described?